# API call failed: Error executing API call (request): Unauthorized request

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate Mollie payment gateway by using these detail

```
$mollie = new Mollie_API_Client;
$mollie->setApiKey('test_dHar4XY7LxsDOtmnkVtjNVWXLSlXsM');

$order_id = time();
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strcasecmp('off', $_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 0 ? "https" : "http";
$hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$path     = dirname(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);


$payment = $mollie->payments->create(array(
        "amount"       => 10.00,
        "description"  => "My first API payment",
        "redirectUrl"  => "{$protocol}://{$hostname}{$path}/3-return-page.php?order_id={$order_id}",
        "metadata"     => array(
            "order_id" => $order_id,
        ),
    ));
```

after run the code it through error

> API call failed: Error executing API call (request): Unauthorized
>   request.

please tell me where i do mistake

THANKS!

Comment: Check this link and be sure that follow each steps http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/401error.htm

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error from the Mollie server. The Mollie API has made a HTTP POST request from your server to Mollie server. The response was: **Unauthorized request**

The most likely reason is that you are using the wrong API key. Visit the [Mollie dashboard](https://www.mollie.com/dashboard/) and copy-paste the appropriate key (either test or live)...